# How to do IIS style compression with Cassini?

Tags: iis, cassini

I have http compression turned on in my production IIS box.  Is there a way to turn it on in the Cassini web server (that comes with VS200x)?

The reason for this is that I am getting slanted performance results and would like the bandwidth in my dev environment to mirror that of production.

Is this possible?

Comment: I'm curious as to how you plan to mirror the bandwidth on your local computer - isn't that be exceedingly difficult? Is there a plugin for your browser that can restrict the bandwidth of local requests to emulate access over the Internet/network?

Comment: @cbp I am looking for the amount of bandwidth, not how fast.  That's easy to measure with Fiddler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the only way I know how to do it is ff you implement your own [Compression Module](http://madskristensen.net/post/HTTP-compression-in-ASPNET-20.aspx) that handles this directly instead of relying on the server you can get compression out of Cassini. If you want the server to handle this for you transparently, I don't think Cassini is built or designed for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can verify for yourself that it isn't possible, the [source code is public](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/10/16/427648.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you are not following the best practices.

You need to set up a test environment after the dev phase. This test environment must be exactly the same as your deployment box. Then you can simulate traffic to the test box in order to find issues. Once tests are done, you can start to deploy.

Cassini is only for dev purposes, so it is meaningless to bring it for test purposes.

Comment: I have all that.  However, the application is a part of a much, much larger suite of products and typically it takes a day after check-in before I see the app on the test box.  Just wanted a quicker turnaround.